# @ControllerAdvice or @ExceptionHandler both not working on gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I have written a very simple gradle spring boot project. But non of my exception handling is working.

Tried handling at @Controller level and also at global via @ControllerAdvice, but both doesn't seems to work.

Could it be because its a gradle project so its not working ?

**Controller class**

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping(value="/test")
    public String testController(){
//        return "Test me";
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value=NullPointerException.class)
    public String handleNPE(Exception e){
        return "Test NPE";
    }

}
```

**Controller Advice class**

```
package MyController;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
public class advice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleNPE(Exception e){
        return "Caught by advisor";
    }
}

Also tried importing ControllerAdvice class explicitly but that doesn't help as well.
```

**build.gradle**

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.12.1'
}
```

**Application class**

````
package com.example.springdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(MyController.advice.class)
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}


}```


github repo - https://github.com/Akashtyagi/SpringBootProject
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at your code & issue is you have wrong annotation `@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller` for `Controller`.

Please note this is rest call & hence you have to use `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController` for controller.

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping(value="/test")
    public String testController(){
//        return "Test me";
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value=NullPointerException.class)
    public String handleNPE(Exception e){
        return "Test NPE";
    }

}
```

Once you change this & execute

```
curl http://localhost:8080/test
```

you will get :

> Test NPE

Comment: glad it worked for you !!, enjoy